# Why are syntax trees binary trees?

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees

In p.26 of *An Introduction to Syntactic Analysis* by Sportiche et al. (2013), the authors specify that syntax trees aren't allowed to have more than two children:

> We never find morphological trees in which:
>
> i. a given node has more than one mother;
>
> ii. a mother has more than two daughters;
>
> iii. any node lacks a mother

Re the second bullet point, a syntax diagram is given that looks something like this:

```
  A
/ | \
C D E
```

So, apparently this is not acceptable when specifying morphological structure; I assume it's the same for syntax trees. This model seems to be exactly the same as a binary tree. Why is this model necessary? I understand that binary trees are very useful structures in computing, but I figured that the use of trees for syntax analysis predated their use in computing. Is there an inherent advantage to using binary trees for syntax diagrams, without considering computing?

Comment: Just mentioning the author and the year is quite unhelpful. It would be nicer if you (a) linked to the paper and (b) pasted one or two of the syntax trees from the paper. That way, your question would be more informative without requiring unnecessarily repeated effort on the part of each person who reads this question. To answer the question as it stands, I'd respond that syntax trees need not be binary, but such a response would be quite unhelpful.

Comment: Sorry, I have a bad habit of never providing enough detail. Hopefully the amended question is clearer.

Comment: This is an artifact of one sect of one version of Chomskyan syntax. There's no evidence that this is the case in natural language, however. One should beware of anyone who says "We never find `X` kind of trees". Trees are not found; trees are constructed by analysts to the specifications of the analysts' theories. This particular one is a requirement of some kinds of Government and Binding, or else Minimalism, or else Naked Phrase Structure. These are all different theories proposed recently by Chomsky; they are all hypotheses, not laws based on analysis.

Comment: I guess, this is what you need: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verb_phrase#Verb_phrases_in_dependency_grammars): *dependency grammars challenge the validity of the initial binary division of the clause into subject (NP) and predicate (VP), which means they reject the notion that the second half of this binary division, i.e. the finite VP, is a constituent.*

Comment: You lost me. Are you talking of morphology or of syntax. Was the book
about morphology or syntax. You say that the statement apparently
concerns morphology and that you assume it applies to syntax. This
seems confusing.

Comment: What is a tree, morphological or otherwise, in which no node lacks a
mother? I would think that any such structure is either infinite or
includes a loop, which is somewhat incompatible with the idea of a
tree. - Then, what could be a tree, morphological or otherwise, in
which a node has more than one mother. Is that so frequent that it is
necessary to exclude such trees? What about excluding trees with blue
eyes and long horns. If any of this makes sense, it is escaping me.
Maybe, what the author calls tree is actually something else. What's
in a Name?

Comment: I add my support to Jlawler's comment above. There is no good evidence supporting the stringly binary branching trees assumed in those versions of GB and the MP

Comment: The book was about morphology and syntax. In the chapter, it was talking about morphology - maybe I made a mistake in extrapolating from morphological trees to syntactic trees; I assumed they were the same.

Comment: I do write my answers carefully. I also believe that my answer here
was useful and documented, since, among other things I checked the
apparently incorrect contextual assumptions. I know I am giving the
point of view of someone with some background in computational
linguistics, but no training in linguistics, and I make it clear.
I think it can nevertheless bring another perspective to issues.
I do resent getting my answer downvoted without a word of explanation
as to what could be wrong in this long answer.

Comment: Puerile as it sounds: it wasn't me. You've got a well-written, thoughtful and considerate answer, I agree.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. Actually my comment was not aimed at you. It is just that there are not many places to put it for people to read. I consider downvoting without comment as rude when addressed to a carefully written answer, even though it may contain errors. Even more so because it is sometimes the downvoter who is wrong. It is also unscientific to do it, but I do not make the rules here.

Comment: Leaving aside questions of whether a vote can be "wrong", I agree that drive-by downvoters are effectively useless.

Comment: What I call wrong vote is vote based on arroneous understanding of issues by the voter, when he downvotes because he believes 2+2=5, and see that you wrote 2+2=4.  (I will have to erase those comments). Regarding your blog: most real numbers are actually not real, no physical existence, not even necessary to do mathematics.

Comment: My blog? I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### My original answer

As I said in a comment I am not completely sure about the
meaning/context of your question. I am answering with respect to
syntax, though my remarks are so general that they could apply to
nearly any context, whether morphological (if you use trees for
morphological structure) or syntactic, or other.

Regarding binary trees, anything that can be represented by trees can
be represented by binary trees, so it may be a matter of
simplification. Another good point of binary trees is that they are
the most convenient and effective for factoring structures and
information. That can help factor linguistic descriptions of language
structures, or factoring ambiguous analyses of a given
sentence.

Technically, though you seem uninterested by computational
consideration, because binary trees give better factorization,
parsing sentences with type 2 grammars (context-free) is faster with
binary trees and also takes less space, when you attempt formally to
analyse ambiguities. The theoretical complexity is in power of n+1,
where n is the maximum number of daughter.

Even though complexity is usually a matter of asymptotic behaviour,
this is not completely irrelevant, because the complexity increase is
observable even on smallish examples. This means that considering only
binary trees might make sense from a psycho-linguistic point of view
... inasmuch as trees are considered relevant for psycho-linguistic
models of whatever you are analyzing.

### Reply to some comments, including my own.

**About the quote**

I do not have access to the 2013 edition of the book, but I did find
what seems to be [an earlier version](http://www.linguistics.ucla.edu/people/stabler/isat.pdf) since it has only 246 pages
instead of 470, and the quoted text does not appear on the same page,
but on page 21 instead of 26.

The quote I found is slightly different as the third bullet point
reads in my version (where it is second):

> It seems that we never find morphological trees in which
>   i. ...
>   ii. more than one node lacks a mother
>   iii. ...

That makes more sense than the quote given in the OP's question, since
otherwise, the structure should be infinite or looping, which is not
compatible with what I know of trees.

But I still fail to understand the reason for excluding morphological
trees in which `i. a given node has more than one mother`. However the
authors states a few lines later that:

> Trees in general then obey the following conditions: i. Every node but
>   one (the "topmost") has a mother ii. No node has more than one mother

So my guess is only that the first bullet of the text quoted in the question was both tautological, and
awkwardly stated. All trees have the property, so that none needs be
excluded on that basis.

**About morphology and syntax**

It is clear from the book that the above quote is about morphology.
I have no opinion about its linguistic accuracy. But it is also clear
that the extension to syntax trees is only the OP's opinion.

Hence it would be better if the comments or answers were clear on
whether they address the book, or the OP's personnal assumptions when stating
`I assume it's the same for syntax trees`, which he does not seem to
sustain with arguments.

Again, I am without opinion on the matter, but this part of the book
does not seem to me to be related to Chomskyan syntax (maybe because
of my ignorance on the matter).

**About the use of binary trees in this morphological context**

My own, probably limited and simplistic, experience of morphology is
that it can most often (with few exceptions) be defined by finite
state machines, defining regular sets. Regular sets of morpheme
strings can be defined by regular grammars, which are either left or
right linear. Representing the sequences as trees rather than strings
would be pointless, except for the fact that left and right linearity
are not normally not mixed (so as to preserve the regular character),
but it seems natural to use one for prefixes and the other for
suffixes (though there is surprisingly no explicit tree example in the
book to justify that). This then justifies exhibiting the structure
with binary trees, that differentiate left and right linearity.

**About the use of binary trees in syntax**

Once again, I want to make it clear that I do not have the
qualification to have an opinion about linguistic theories. But I do
have experience and opinions (that I can hopefully sustain) about
formalization techniques.

I was clear that my statements are of a very general nature, and thus
do not support any linguistic theory over another. It is only my way
to give a kind of general support to the idea of binarization, which
is more than the OP did, as far as I can tell.

When I state that binary branching structures are more efficient, all
I mean, and I said as much, is that it helps factoring. If you use a
context-free grammar, you can use the rules:
     `{ A --> BCF , A --> DEF }`
  or `{ A --> UF , U --> BC , U --> DE }`
If you have for some reason an ambiguity between BC and DE, you can at
least share the information regarding the presence of F at the end.

There is at least one situation where this efficiency gain shows as a
complexity result, which is context-free parsing. Its complexity is
lower on binarized grammars ...  or at least binarized parse-tree (to
make sure to cover an apparently little known point about Earley's
algorithm). If this is not a solid example, I do not know what is.  I
am however conscious of the fact that asymptotic arguments are of
limited value ([which some seem to ignore](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6003/does-the-p-versus-np-conjecture-in-computer-science-have-any-direct-relevance-to)), becahave its valueuse the brain deals
only with small examples, but I did try to account for that in my answer.

The wording of my answer (above) was careful. I was expecting
reactions about the existence of structures that should be viewed as
ternary, or more. I do not deny that, and spoke of *representation*.
The fact is that a representation is chosen for convenience, and can
then be abstracted for perspicuity if deemed necessary. Abstraction
may mean seeing one ternary node where representation uses two binary
ones. And while the ternary view may be essential, there is still the possibility that the binary view is relevant in a different context.

So even if you do consider that the ternary aspect of `A --> BCF` is
essential, you can represent it with `A --> UF , U --> BC`, while
specifying that `U --> BC` has no meaning on its own.

Once again, my intent is only to see what general arguments can be given
for binarization, on an abstract basis, without attempting to consider
any specific syntactic theory of language.

Comment: This answer is really not comprehensible for the average reader in this forum. What is needed are examples. If one is going to argue that strictly binary branching structures can be more efficient (computationally or otherwise), then a solid example or two are needed to demonstrate the point. I don't think they are more efficient.

Comment: The answer claims: "anything that can be represented by trees can be represented by binary trees,...". That claim is demonstrably false. Strictly binary branching trees assume more structure than flatter trees. The flatter trees are closer to what diagnostics for constituents tell us about syntactic structure. The proponents of the strictly binary branching structures do their best to ignore the results of the diagnostics (topicalization, clefting, pseudoclefting, proform substitution, answer fragments, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications to your original answer. I now mostly understand your points. My first response was concerned with linguistic reasoning in syntax. In my view, there is strong linguistic evidence in favor of n-ary branching structures in syntax. This evidence comes in the form of the diagnostics for constituent structure. I think the proponents of strict binarity of branching in syntax either consciously or subconsciously ignore this evidence. This ignorance evokes a strong reaction from me.

Comment: Concerning the computational efficiency you describe, I mostly understand, and the reasoning given may be correct, although I am not a computational linguist. Further, the fact that Sportiche's original claim applies to morphsyntax (as opposed to syntax in general) may also be correct. I am not aware of linguistic evidence of n-ary branching inside words.

Comment: @TimOsborne The disconcerting gap between computational and linguistic
perpective on issues shows also in morphology
structure. Computationally (complexity excepted) binary or n-ary
branching are equivalent, so that no evidence of n-ary branching would
not make a difference.  While the morphological tree structure may
seem more perspicuous, the real computational issue is whether we can
ignore the tree altogether, and rely only on a finite
partitioning of allowed constructions, i.e. on a finite state
machine. I wonder whether there are other such differences in
perspective. A question, maybe.

Comment: Note that whenever an argument is repeated (even if via a pronoun), the deep structure will have a node with more than one mother.  The reason that sentences correspond to trees is that sentences are necessarily 'one dimensional', and the deeper 'loops' need to be broken to be spoken.

Answer (score 4):

There are several different views on the acceptability of trees where a mother has more than two daughters (i.e. non-binary branching).  Much current work in the Minimalist Program (e.g. the Sportiche work cited) allows only binary trees.  In earlier versions of syntactic theory (e.g. Chomsky 1981), non-binary trees were allowed.  And in some alternatives to Minimalist Program (e.g. LFG, HPSG), such non-binary trees are still allowed.

The emphasis on binary trees owes much to the work of Richard Kayne, who has argued that they are the only kind that should be allowed.

Comment: As far as I know, the answer is accurate. What is interesting for me, however, is the linguistic evidence for and against the strictly binary branching trees. What evidence can be produced supporting it. See the discussion here: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6826/what-empirical-evidence-can-be-produced-that-all-syntactic-structure-is-binary-b.